# linq in or contains?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

How can I use Linq-to-sql to a search like this:

where obj.id equals any of the following {1,2,3,4}

I would guess I could use the in or perhaps contains?

where obj.id in Enumerable.Range( (int) myEnum.Start, (int) myEnum.End) ) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `.Contains()`, like this:

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 5 };
var result = from s in DB.Something
             where list.Contains(s.Id)
             select s;
```

This will get translated to a parameterized form of:

```
WHERE Id IN (1, 2, 3, 5)
```

Comment: Hi Nick. What about if you replace var list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 5 }; with a list of objects of some type that has members like i.e. ID and Name and you want to use member ID within the Contains?

It cannot start with list.Contains anymore. How would you write this query in this case?

I ask because I have got this situation and don't know how to solve it. Instead of list of objectss and List<int> I have two lists of objects and want to use their ID members.

Regards
Mariusz

Answer (score 0):

```
var myCustomers = new short[] {1,2,3,4};
var foo = db.Customers.Where(c=> myCustomers.Contains(c.ID));
```

Comment: @Johannes: careful not to paste this sample code into your production app!