# Linq to have "IN" clause like SQL

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I want to do this in linq:
SQL: select from customer where city in ('Berlin','London','Madrid','Bern',Graz')

So I have a string like shown below:

```
string city ="'Berlin','London','Madrid','Bern','Graz'"
var query = from c in Customers 
            where c.City ==??
            select c;
```

The string variable will change...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [linq in or contains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024883/linq-in-or-contains)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out...

```
string[] city2 = { "Berlin", "London", "Madrid", "Bern", "Graz" };
var query2 = from c in Customers
            where city2.Contains(c.City)
            select c;
```